# Display html.Div after nth post within Wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Using custom wordpress loop:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
//Post Content
<?php endwhile;?>
//Pagination
<?php else : ?>
//No posts message
<?php endif; ?>
```

I need help restructure the code to display html Div.block *after 4th post each page* on condition that page has at least 6 posts to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined `$postnum` before my loop through each result, so that the original value of `$postnum` can be incremented each iteration.

```
<?php 
$postnum = 0; // Set counter to 0 outside the loop
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
  //Post Content
<?php $postnum++; // Increment counter
if ($postnum == 4){ ?>
  //Div.block
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
  //Pagination
<?php else : ?>
  //No posts message
<?php endif; ?>
```

That way, I was able to display single Div.block html after 4th post on each page within loop.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress uses the object WPQuery in The Loop, and in the object you have two variables that you can use to determine the number of posts that you will display on the page. The variables are `$wp_query->post_count;` and `$wp_query->found_posts;` if you declare the $wp_query like this `$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );`.

Now, I will add a little counter in your loop, and it will become this:

```
<?php 
$size = $wp_query->post_count;
$counter = 0;
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
//Post Content
    if ($size >= 6 && $counter == 3) {
        //show your div here
    }

    $counter++;
<?php endwhile;?>
    //Pagination
<?php else : ?>
    //No posts message
<?php endif; ?>
```